# why JavaScript array is working differently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = arr1;

console.log(arr1 === arr2);

arr1 = [1, 2];

console.log(arr1 === arr2);
console.log('array1 ', arr1);
console.log('array2 ', arr2);
```

if array is reference type, so arr2 value should be change

Comment: arr1 is being overwritten, while its referred object is still being referred by arr2.

Comment: arr2 contains a reference to "1,2,3,4,5", but never a reference to "arr1".

Comment: If you want to see how arrays are reference values, you'd need to mutate the array: `arr1.length = 2`. Not assign a different value to the variable.

Comment: Related question: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Does that mean we are creating a copy of a reference that points to an object or array?

Answer (score 0):

at `arr1 = [1, 2]` value of the array is reassigned and hence it creates a new reference.

you can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20it%27s%20just%20NOT,can%20be%20assigned%20by%20reference.&text=Bottom%20line%3A,value%20or%20assign%2Dby%2Dreference)

Comment: value of the array is reassigned and hence it creates a new reference. 